# Drag and Drop Drawing in Web

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring, drag-and-drop

The problem is to create a dynamic label printing where in I will present to the user the fields that are available (ex. Name, ID No, Address etc) and I will let them draw their own label.

It is something like on the left side, there are the available fields, and on the right side is a big field where I let them drag and drop the fields and draw boxes and grids.

The system should be able to save the drawing (in any format as long as it can be saved in the database) that they created and the fields in that drawing can be called in the backend.

The saving part is important because if the user created so many labels, I want them to be able to choose which drawing they can use to Print their labels.

I would like to integrate this with my existing web Maven Spring 3.x system.

If anybody could point to where to look, either in the drawing creation or in the saving it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I did that drawing/saving stuff in a webapp some time ago using Javascript. Use the HTML canvas element to define a place users can draw on.

Guess there are several js/jquery libraries for that (It is also possible to do everything on your own)

There are also exporting functionalities (I do not remember exactly) but it is possible to convert the drawing to a data-url and upload it with a hidden text field. Of course it can be directly stored on the user's computer as well.

Start by having a look at [introduction to canvas drawing on w3cschools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)